# How do I prevent SharePoint Designer from adding a Byte Order Mark to my XML files?

Tags: xml, rss

We have some hand crafted XML files we use for various rss needs.  Whenever a dev updates the file, SharePoint Designer adds an UTF-8 byte order mark to the beginning of the file causing some parsers to complain about it.  Currently, I can open the file in vim or a hex editor and remove the mark, but is there a way to make SharePoint Designer not do this?

Edit: Were using SharePoint Designer 2007.  However, we do plan to upgrade to SharePoint 2010 later, so if there is any insight there, I would be very appreciative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can fix this by opening the site in sharepoint designer, going to "Site Options" -> "Language" and choosing a "Default Page Encoding" other than UTF-8.

Comment: I went with US/Western European ISO encoding, and that got me where I need to go.  I appreciate the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the XML editor in the Application Options under Tools to Notepad inside SharePoint Designer. Try that and see if SharePoint Designer behaves.

Comment: I didn't have to use Notepad after all, but your answer sent me in the right direction.  Cheers.